# Ошибка SIGSEGV выход за пределы памяти

Tags: c, массивы

Решал задачки на leetcode.com подсмотрел решение получше у одного из пользователей (kljsandjb) часть кода

```
bool isValid(char * s){  
  size_t s_Len = strlen (s);
  size_t stack_size = 0;  
  char * stack = (char *)malloc (s_Len * sizeof(char));
  if ((s[0] = 0) || (s_Len <= 1))
    return false;...
```

при воспроизведении добавил проверку
`if ((s[0] = 0) || (s_Len <= 1)) return false;` если не комментировать эти строки ловлю ошибку SIGSEGV.

## Внимание вопрос:

Почему плохо обращаться к `s[0]` в этом месте?

---

Далее по тексту я присваиваю и проверяю в цикле FOR от `s[0]` и до `s[s_Len]`, когда проблемные строки закомментированы программа работает.

Comment: Чему равно `s` при вызове этой функции? И Вы же понимаете, что `s[0]=0` это присваивание, а не проверка на равенство нулю?

Answer (score -1):

Благодаря комментарию [@Vladimir](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1364302/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-sigsegv-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8/1364317#comment2421023_1364302):

> s[0]=0 это присваивание, а не проверка на равенство нулю

Ошибка - некорректное использование оператора `=`.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Правильно писать The_Stupid_Watchmaker.